# What was Ego's motive exactly?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2

[Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3896198/) Spoilers ahead.

May be I wasn't paying enough attention. Thus, miss the plot. So Ego wanted to find a person or a entity, who would carry the energy that he needed in order to spread the light of Ego's planet everywhere. Right ? That's why he spread some seed like thing everywhere in the universe.

But why? I mean what was the big plan? Was he wanted to kill all life but himself / itself? If not then why destroying only habitable planets? He could have use any planet without life to spread the Ego planet's branch.

Comment: He wanted to become everything

Comment: I cannot remember exactly if he planted the seeds on life-less planets or not, but his intention was to be the universe. Boosting his _ego_ in the process. 
Just like how people with ego do not care for people who they are below them, ego did not bother with life-less planets. Doing so would only waste his efforts and would not add to his ego

Comment: @AtulBhatS Got it now. I guess I missed the plot. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ego (the concept) is defined as

> "a person's sense of self-esteem or self-importance."

Ego (the planet/person/god), is the literal depiction of the concept of Ego. So Ego's motivation is to grow his Ego (sense of self importance), by becoming everything in the universe. Of-course he doesn't have the power to do this on his own.